# How to push duplicates into an array with Laravel pluck()?

Tags: laravel

In the example below, taken from Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck), if duplicate keys exist, the last matching element will be inserted into the plucked collection:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['brand' => 'Tesla',  'color' => 'red'],
    ['brand' => 'Pagani', 'color' => 'white'],
    ['brand' => 'Tesla',  'color' => 'black'],
    ['brand' => 'Pagani', 'color' => 'orange'],
    ['brand' => 'Renault', 'color' => null],
]);

$plucked = $collection->pluck('color', 'brand');

$plucked->all();

// ['Tesla' => 'black', 'Pagani' => 'orange', 'Renault' => null]
```

How can I get all duplicates into an array like below instead ?

```
[
  'Tesla' => ['red', 'black'],
  'Pagani' => ['white', 'orange'],
  'Renault' => null,
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this will work as you want

```
$collection = collect([
  ['brand' => 'Tesla', 'color' => 'red'],
  ['brand' => 'Pagani', 'color' => 'white'],
  ['brand' => 'Tesla', 'color' => 'black'],
  ['brand' => 'Pagani', 'color' => 'orange'],
  ['brand' => 'Renault', 'color' => null],
]);
$plucked = $collection->groupBy('brand')->map(function ($brands) {
  $data = $brands->pluck('color');
  return $data[0] ? $data : null;
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! How to get only the brand with `null` value instead of empty array `[null]`  when there's only one color set to `null` ? (I have updated my question)

Answer (score 3):

there is a method specialized for this case, it's [mapToGroups](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-maptogroups):

The mapToGroups method groups the collection's items by the given closure. The closure should return an associative array containing a single key / value pair, thus forming a new collection of grouped values:

```
 $collection = collect([
            ['brand' => 'Tesla',  'color' => 'red'],
            ['brand' => 'Pagani', 'color' => 'white'],
            ['brand' => 'Tesla',  'color' => 'black'],
            ['brand' => 'Pagani', 'color' => 'orange'],
            ['brand' => 'Renault', 'color' => null],
        ]);
        $grouped = $collection->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
            return [$item['brand'] => $item['color']];
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I get `'Renault' => null` instead of `'Renault' => [ null ]` ?